# Exception (stacktrace) not available in springboot unit test

Tags: java, spring-boot, exception, junit5

I am starting to use spring boot framework and stumble on every second step.
Currently I have a situation which i absolutely do not understand.

I am using spring boot 2.3.5.RELEASE building with maven

```
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>${java.version}</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>${java.version}</maven.compiler.target>
    </properties>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.5.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/>
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>

    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate.validator/hibernate-validator -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.validator</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.6.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- OpenAPi (swagger)-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.32</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
```

I created a rather simple class RESTCommunication. No @Component, @Controller or similar.

```
public class RESTCommunication {
    private final Logger m_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());
    private String m_contentType;
    private String m_path;    
    private String m_body;

    private HashMap<String,String> m_urlParams;
    private HashMap<String,String> m_queryParams;

    public RESTCommunication() {
    m_logger.debug("RESTCommunication constructor");
        
    m_scheme    = RESTCommunication.SCHEME_DEFAULT;
    m_authority = RESTCommunication.AUTHORITY_DEFAULT;
    m_port      = RESTCommunication.PORT_DEFAULT;
    m_path      = RESTCommunication.PATH_DEFAULT;

    m_urlParams = new HashMap<>();
    // m_queryParams = new HashMap<>();  // I know that this is the reason for the exception
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    StringBuilder sbToString = new StringBuilder();
    sbToString.append(buildURI());
    sbToString.append("|numURLParams:").append(m_urlParams.size());
    sbToString.append("|numQueryParams:").append(m_queryParams.size());  // This has to fail because m_queryParams is not initialized
    return sbToString.toString();
}
    .....
```

For this class i created a very simple test class RESTCommunicationTest

```
@SpringBootTest
public class RESTCommunicationTest {
    private final Logger m_logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(this.getClass());

    @Test
    public void defaultInitTest() {
        RESTCommunication restComm = new RESTCommunication();
  
        String restCommURL = restComm.toString();  // Expect the nullpointer INSIDE the toString method
        String expectedURL = sbExpected.toString();
        
        assertEquals(expectedURL, restCommURL, "Expected URL does not match generated");
    }
```

I run the test with the command: `$./mvnw -e -X package -Dtest=RESTCommunicationTest#defaultInitTest`
And as expectable i see the Nullpointer in the stdout logging.
BUT in the logging I find this:

```
webServerFactoryCustomizerBeanPostProcessor
websocketServletWebServerCustomizer
welcomePageHandlerMapping
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 3.532 s <<< FAILURE! - in org.highpots.hippo.core.communication.RESTCommunicationTest
[ERROR] defaultInitTest  Time elapsed: 0.399 s  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                    
    at org.ilovespringboot.not.RESTCommunicationTest.defaultInitTest(RESTCommunicationTest.java:36)

2020-12-08 22:18:10.810  INFO 10381 --- [extShutdownHook] o.s.s.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor  : Shutting down ExecutorService 'applicationTaskExecutor'
[INFO]
[INFO] Results:
[INFO]
[ERROR] Errors:
[ERROR]   RESTCommunicationTest.defaultInitTest:36 » NullPointer
[INFO]
[ERROR] Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0
```

A nullpointer in RESTCommunicationTest.java:36. Absolutely no hint that the real NullPointer happens in RESTCommunication class.
Can someone explain my that behaviour? Am I doing something wrong?
I know I am some kind of programming dinosaurs. (java projects are about 10+ years in the past). But I would expect to get a hint where the exception is thrown. I would expect a stacktrace with detailed caused by sections.
If can not imagine this is not normal behavior. Because that would mean I have to find all errors by mind-stepping through the complete source... This is not possible

Tanks for your help in advance
Harri E

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maven uses surefire plugin to run tests.To see Exception stacktrace you must set **trimStackTrace** to **false** in surefire plugin configuration.

Historically surefire plugin use to print complete stacktrace. Though the information in the stack trace was useful for debugging, stack traces took up rather a lot of space in the console output. Particularly if there were a number of failing tests it became easy to get lost in the noise.

Since version 2.13 surefire just prints summary by default.

```
    <build>
      <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>${your.maven.surefire.version.here}</version>
            <configuration>
                <trimStackTrace>false</trimStackTrace>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
      </plugins>
    </build>
```

Comment: That solved the problem. 
Thank you very much. You saved my life :-)